# Return read-only 2-D array from class

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a class which contains a large array. I would like to make the array private, but I need to read a lot of data from it, but make sure it never be changed by anything outside of the class. Is there any way to reference an array such that it can be read from, but not written to?

EDIT: this class is going to be distributed, and I want to prevent unauthorized access to all private members. This seems to make it so that any type of referencing impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can return a const reference to the `vector<vector <T>>` (you are using vector, not allocating memory yourself, right).

Something like:

```
class MyCLass
{
  private:
    vector<vector<T>> v;
    ...
  public:
    ...
    const vector<vector<T>>& getVector()  const { return v; }
};
```

Comment: Maybe a little paranoid here, but couldn't the person create a vector<vector<T> >&, and do a type-cast to force assign it?

Comment: Sure, and if they want to, they could take the address of the object, figure out where the offset is for your vector and cast an pointer to vector to it. If you are that bloody-minded to get to the data, it's always possible. What you want is for someone to not ACCIDENTALLY access the data.... [Unless we're talking things that really need security - passcodes to get into Pentagon or something - but then you would probably rely on hardware, not software to prevent access].

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this do?

```
class ReadOnlyArray
{
private:
    float mData[SIZE][SIZE];
public:
    float Get( int i, int j ) const { return mData[i][j]; }
};
```

Comment: That would work, and inline quite nicely, so should not make too much overhead.

Comment: It would work, but a function call would have a large overhead, and with the large amounts of data being retrieved, I was hoping for something which can operate at the speed of a subscript operator, though if not possible I could inline this function and hope for the best.

Comment: I bet you that you won't see a difference between this and using "reference copy" like I suggested - as long as the `Get` function is in a header that is included by the code calling `Get`, it should inline nicely [unless if `mData` is not a plain array, and `operator[]` for `mData` or `mData[]` is complicated - but then it wouldn't really help to pass a `const referecne` to `mData` back either].

Answer (score 1):

Make the array private. Create public functions to retrieve and return data from the array.